# Object detection in static image using Tensorflow

Tags: android, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

is it possible to detect the object on a static image using TensorFlow. Most of the tutorials I found on the internet are using a live camera. I currently working on an android app that can detect an object after taking a photo. I'm wondering if is it possible.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Defenitely, all basic object detections are running on images only. The live feed from a camera or a video file is taken frame by frame for processing with object detection methods. Unless, a temporal analysis is used, the object detections are simply running inference on each of the frames of the video.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run on captured images, just sharing a demo link where its demonstrated for prototyping -

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/object_detection.ipynb

Github link- 
https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/object_detection.ipynb

You can run this in colab to test with any image of your choice.